# Add equation number in an array

Tags: equations, numbering

I am trying to add equation number in the last two lines.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{ll}

\max\limits_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1)(a_1-b_1*p_1)\\

\max\limits_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2)(a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1\\

{s.t.} &\\

p_1\le p_2 & \hfill(\text{when } a_1\le a_2)\\

x_1r_1 \le p_2 &\hfill (\text{when } a_2 < a_1)

\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `array` is for arrays and matrices, it is not designed for displayed equations, use the ams `align` enviornment

Comment: I know that part but the desired output is difficult to achieve in align.

Comment: you just want to number the constraints not the main equation? do you want to number each of those two lines, or one number between the pair?

Comment: In this case, number each constraint separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with `alignat`. I also suggest to use  the `subequations` environment, but if you don't want it  for some reason, just remove it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \max_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1) & & (a_1-b_1*p_1) \notag \\
\max_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2) & & (a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1 \notag \\
\text{s. t.\enspace}p_1 & \le p_2 & & (\text{when } a_1\le a_2) \\
                x_1r_1 & \le p_2 & & (\text{when } a_2 < a_1)
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

note array uses inline math not display so isn't suitable for displayed equations, you partially compensated by `\limits` on the `\max` but it still uses a compressed layout vertically and exessive space horizontally around the `&`.

I would do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

zzz
\begin{align*}
\max_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1)(a_1-b_1*p_1)\\
\max_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2)(a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1
\end{align*}
s.t.
\begin{align}
p_1\le p_2 && (\text{when } a_1\le a_2)\\
x_1r_1 \le p_2 &&(\text{when } a_2 < a_1)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Everything should be left aligned with 's.t.'. I could achieve this result but I am not happy with it.

Comment: you could use `fleqn` option but I guess that you want the equations centred? As I say I'd use the form above as the left hand side of each row is right aligned to the = or < so there isn't a natural left edge to put the s.t and arguably it is part of the surrounding sentence, but you could add it instead to last row of the first `align` if you wanted that?

Comment: @MKC note to get left aligmnent you have to have asymmetric spacing around the = in the first two rows as shown in your image which is always going to look very odd.

Comment: I modified your code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses above, I experimented with the following codes and the outputs are as follow:

[Output](https://ibb.co/hck2ke)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}

\max_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1)(a_1-b_1*p_1) \nonumber \\ 

\max_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2)(a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1 \nonumber\\ 

\text{s.t.} \nonumber\\

p_1\le p_2 && (\text{when } a_1\le a_2)\\

x_1r_1 \le p_2 &&(\text{when } a_2 < a_1)

\end{flalign}

\begin{align}

\max_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1)(a_1-b_1*p_1) \nonumber \\ 

\max_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2)(a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1 \nonumber\\ 

\text{s.t.} \nonumber\\

p_1\le p_2 && (\text{when } a_1\le a_2)\\

x_1r_1 \le p_2 &&(\text{when } a_2 < a_1)

\end{align}

\begin{subequations}

\begin{alignat}{2}

\max_{p_1} \pi_R &=(p_1-c_1) & & (a_1-b_1*p_1) \notag \\

\max_{p_2,x_1} \pi_C &=(p_2-c_2) & & (a_2-b_2*p_2)-x_1r_1 \notag \\

\text{s. t.\enspace} \notag \\

p_1 & \le p_2 & & (\text{when } a_1\le a_2) \\

x_1r_1 & \le p_2 & & (\text{when } a_2 < a_1)

\end{alignat}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```